# Inequality confusion regarding less than or greater than

Tags: inequality

I know this question might seem obvious but I am generally confused to if this holds true and can be used when writing proofs in some steps in problems:

$$2 \le 2, \space |x_2-x_1| \le |x_2-x_1|\space \text{:etc....}$$

I would appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Yes...$x≤x$ for any real $x$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: yes ok thanks ! that cleared it up instantly.

Comment: I don't know how this is coming up in what you're doing, but this reminds me of a common proof method to show that several numbers (or objects in a linearly ordered set) are equal. Say you want to prove $x_1$ and $x_2$ and $x_3$ are equal to each other. If you can prove $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq x_1,$ then it follows that $x_1 = x_2 = x_3.$ Indeed, under the order "implies", this method can also be used to show that several statements are equivalent. If you can show "(1) implies (2) implies (3) implies (1)", then it follows that "(1) if and only if (2) if and only if (3)".